# WebView ignore Cache policy on subsequent pages

Tags: ios, caching, webview, policy

I have noticed that in my webView, I've set the cache policy when making request, in viewDidLoad,

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];
```

the cache will runs for the first time only and when I click another button in the web page to proceed to the subsequent pages, the webView ignores the cache policy , making it only load faster on the very first page of the web page. The subsequent pages are loaded very slowly.

How can I solve this problem: make all the subsequent pages load as fast as the first-loaded page in webView?

Comment: Its because, you are making only the first url to have the cache property.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I guess I have found the solution and answer to my own question now. It seems like I can put

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120]; ]
```

inside the webView delegate of

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

if navigationType is equal to `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`, to make a new request with the method which allows me to set the cache policy.

Comment: Hi, I know this is quite old, but how did you override the UIWebView behavior of setting the cache policy to "ignore local cached data" for subsequent requests? Did you just return NO in the method after calling loadRequest: with the newly created request?